# Per-kind namespace

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a project that will need data to be separated.

There will be multiple 'systems' that will be implemented. Each will be based on a general model. To have this in the GAE datastore, I could use a prefix: `4EClass`, `3EClass` and `PthClass`. I would rather use the namespaces for this as it seems to be cleaner.

I would like to be able to set a namespace in the kind's subclass:

```
class Class(db.Model):
    namespace = '4E'
```

Is there a way to get put, query, etc to work with these namespaces preferably without having to do `Class.query(namespace=Class.namespace)` or the like?

Comment: Your question is very unclear (at least to me).  Maybe you're looking for [modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)?

Comment: did you check out polymodels?  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass

Answer (score 1):

Using namespaces for this does not make a great deal of sense - namespaces are orthogonal to model classes.

Instead, you can specify a kind name independently of the class name:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
  @classmethod
  def kind(cls):
    return "MyModel_Foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for are polymodels. here with ndb: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass
or db: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass

and i also would suggest you to use `ndb` instead of the `db` package.
  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass

Comment: I may use PolyModels, but I am looking for a way to set the namespace in the Model (or PolyModel) subclass.

Comment: what is the reason you want to use namespaces? with polymodels you can query for the subclass of the model and query over all submodels by using the superclass. using namespaces would limit you to do that but maybe you have a reason for that.

Comment: I want to use namespaces because I have potentially large amount of overlapping, independent sections.